# I get require is not defined error if I call it from external files

Tags: node.js

Hi,

I made an app for node.js so my app.js looks like this:

```
global.fs = require("fs");
global.vm = require('vm');

var includefile = function(path) {
    var code = fs.readFileSync(path);
    vm.runInThisContext(code, path);
}.bind(this);

includefile("variables.js");
```

as for variables.js I have this:

```
global.app = require("express")();
```

but when I start the app I get this error:

```
require is not defined at variables.js
```

why is it that requires loads fine if executed from app.js but not from an external file?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have your package set up to use ES6 module `import` statements instead of `require()`?

Comment: where do I check that?

Comment: Inside your `package.json` file do you have a line which reads `"type": "module",`? If so, `require()` calls won't work.

Comment: `global.fs = require("fs");` is an anti-pattern.  Use modules, imports, exports, not globals.

Comment: no, I have not that line in my json. Also, I use global because otherwise the variables declared on app.js wont work on functions defined on functions.js which is a file in the same folder as app.js

Comment: Whats the purpose of running everything inside a new vm/context when you make everything accessable from everywhere? As jfriend00 said, this is a anti patern. I think you have a missunderstanding how "modules" (import/export) in node.js work

Comment: granted, Im confused so thats why Im asking here how can I link to external files instead of having everything in the same app.js file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused, is `variables.js` just another source file in your project? All you should need to do is require the file in like you've done at the top. As an example for `variables.js`:

```
const Variables = {
   fs: "some_value"
};

module.exports = Variables;
```

And for `app.js`

```
const { Variables } = require("./variables.js");

const fs = Variables.fs;
```

Executing `console.log(fs);` in `app.js` will print "some_value". Same can be done with functions.

Comment: I dont know if you can call it that but the thing here is that I used to have everything inside app.js and since that file was getting too long I decided to break it into many files, like one for the variables only, other for the functions alone and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If `variables.js` is part of your project code, you should use the answer of [M. Gercz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70647728/10838441).

If it's not part of your project code and you want to get some information from it, you could use a json file:

app.js

```
const variables = require('variables.json');
console.log(variables.whatever);
```

variables.json

```
{ whatever: "valuable information" }
```

If it's not certain, that `variables.json` is preset, you can do a check using [fs.existsSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsexistssyncpath);

Notice: As [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) commented, using `global` is not recommended.

Comment: it is part of my project, it used to be part of app.js but I made it into a new file of the sake of organization.

Comment: @CainNuke This is good, you shoud absolutely encapsulate logic or information in different files. If you have simple predefined values, you want to access in `app.js`, then you can use a json file. If some the values are dynamic (need to be computed at runtime), then use a module, like in the answer of M. Gercz.